# How do you track timestamps with Appscript function and Importrange column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently, I'm trying to find a way to track the changes of various cell changes with individual time stamps. I want to track changes so that every time one of these rows changes it marks a new time stamp in another column. I need to it to track every time that some make a change with a new time stamp in a new column.

Do you think someone could help me?

This is the function I am using and I was just going to set up a trigger to go off every day. I'm not sure this is the best way to track this type of change either so I am open to other suggestions if anyone has any. The only think is that an onEdit function DOESN'T work when you are using importrange for values. I put an example of the work I'm using here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PLmkEmJ6sMeu1Y-8mEJ5FaSNIXVnzEuYrilFNA7G0Pk/edit#gid=464181309

.js I was trying to use:

```js
function checkCompleted() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  s.getRange('G2:H').getValues()
  .forEach (function (r, i) {
  if(r[0] == 'Completed' && !r[1])
  s.getRange(i + 2, 8).setValue(new Date())
  })
}
```

Comment: Check out this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/urlfetch-and-oauth/get-the-revision-history-of-a-resource-using-docslist-api).

Comment: @pnuts Would you have another suggestion? I am not such an experienced developer here.

Comment: @cooper thanks! this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

## Change tracking Log

The problem with tracking changes by just changing the time stamp is that you only have knowledge of the last change to a given line. So I would suggest just writing a short message into a log entry that you can come back and read anytime.  This will include a time stamp, spreadsheet name, sheet name, range changed, oldvalue and new value.  You will need to create a file.  I use Drive Notepad to create the file and I put all of these sorts of files in one data folder and you'll need the id of the data folder.  You'll also need the id of your spreadsheet and the name of the sheet you wish to log the edits of.

You'll need to create an onEdit trigger for the onEditLog function.

**The Code:**

```
function onEditLog(e)
{
  var ss=e.source.openById('SpreadsheetId');
  var docnam=ss.getname();
  var shtnam=ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var range=e.range.getA1Notation();
  if(docnam=='Your Document Name' && shtnam=='Sheet1')
  {
    var msg= 'Spreadsheet: ' + docnam + ' Sheet: ' + shtnam + + 'Range: ' + range +  ' has been changed from ' + e.oldvalue + ' to ' + e.value;
    logEntry1(msg,'filename');
  }

}

function logEntry1(entry,file)//not you cannot run this function like other functions from your script editor.  It must be run from an onEdit trigger so that it has access to the event object.
{
  var file = (typeof(file) != 'undefined')?file:'eventlog.txt';
  var entry = (typeof(entry) != 'undefined')?entry:'No entry string provided.';
  if(entry)
  {
    var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'hh:mm:ss a");
    var s = ts + ' - ' + entry + '\n';
    saveFile(s, file, true);
  }
}

//this function is taken from myUtility library you'll need to add your own DefaultFileName and DataFolderID. 
function saveFile(datstr,filename,append)
{
  var append = (typeof(append) !== 'undefined')? append : false;
  var filename = (typeof(filename) !== 'undefined')? filename : DefaultFileName;//make change here. It is a string so put quotes around it.
  var datstr = (typeof(datstr) !== 'undefined')? datstr : '';
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : DataFolderID;//make other change here.  Again it is a string 
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var file = fldr.getFilesByName(filename);
  var targetFound = false;
  while(file.hasNext())
  {
    var fi = file.next();
    var target = fi.getName();
    if(target == filename)
    {
      if(append)
      {
        datstr = fi.getBlob().getDataAsString() + datstr;
      }
      targetFound = true;
      fi.setContent(datstr);
    }
  }
  if(!targetFound)
  {
    var create = fldr.createFile(filename, datstr);
    if(create)
    {
      targetFound = true;
    }
  }
  return targetFound;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cooper, the problem I am running into with this is that the changes are coming from an importrange, which OnEdit can't track with AppScript.

Comment: I may have to rethink this process entirely though if there is no easy work around to using OnEdit's with ImportatRange. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well since your using importRange I think I can assume your getting data from another sheet or spreadsheet.  I don't how the source gets it's data but if it's linked to a form you could use the on Form Submit or you could use a time trigger and copy the row you want and append to the destination sheet and I think either of those can be detected by onChange trigger.  Or you could do the calculations from the source spreadsheet script.